# Error when creating Database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting the error bellow, when I try to create my database using Entity Framework Core

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_StudentAnnouncements_Students_StudentId' on table 'StudentAnnouncements' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I have a one to many relationship between `Student` and `StudentAnnouncements`. My `Student` entity has the code below

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentAnnouncement> StudentAnnouncements { get; set;}
}
```

My `StudentAnnouncement` entity has the code below

```cs
public class StudentAnnouncement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a migration and update the database using `dotnet ef database update` I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Cascade delete means that when a Student is deleted, all rows referencing that Student in the StudentAnnouncements table will be deleted as well, so that there is no Student Announcement that point to an inexistent Student. What you have here is a scenario where cascade delete will have impact in multiple entities. In other words, if a Student is deleted, some other table besides StudentAnnouncements is going to have rows deleted as well and SQL Server doesn't like that ambiguity. You have to choose what you really want to be deleted and what will be kept.

It's possible to change the default behavior of cascade deleting in the DbContext OnConfiguring() method, using Fluent API. You can learn about that configuration here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#configuring-cascading-behaviors

Comment: so does this mean I have to manually go through related child entities and delete those before I can delete a related parent

Answer (score 0):

The problem at foreign key named `FK_StudentAnnouncements_Students_StudentId` on table `StudentAnnouncements`.

Choose one of these solutions:

**(1)** Delete foreign key `FK_StudentAnnouncements_Students_StudentId` in database, re-run Entity Framework Core scaffolding.

**(2)** Specify `ON DELETE NO ACTION`

**(3)** Specify `UPDATE NO ACTION`

Sample syntax

```sql
CREATE TABLE child_table
( 
 col_1 data_type [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
 col_2 data_type [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
 …

 CONSTRAINT fk_name
  FOREIGN KEY (child_col_1, child_col_2, … child_col_n)
  REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col_1, parent_col_2, … parent_col_n) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  [ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]
);
```

Let's me know result.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. but I have decided to write methods that delete child records first before deleting parent records. I am using on delete restrict